# Subtract 11 from entire list of quoted numbers

Tags: python, list, subtraction

I need to subtract 11 just from every quoted number on the list. I have looked everywhere for help on this topic except here.

Here is the code:

```
list1 = [ 1, '33', 2, '49', 3, '63']

print(list1-11)
```

Comment: Do you want to substract 11 from all elements in the list, or only from those that are strings ("quoted")?

Answer (score 4):

This is one approach using `isinstance` to check type and a list comprehension.

**Ex:**

```
lst = [ 1, '33', 2, '49', 3, '63']
print([int(i) - 11 if isinstance(i, str) else i for i in lst])
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 22, 2, 38, 3, 52]
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, I have another question.  How do you now use modular arithmetic on this part of the list I wish to use mod 121 on it:                                                                  lst = [22, 236, 23, 242, 24, 248 ] I wish to only mod each number after the enumeration like 236, 242 and 248 by mod 121.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast those string values to int using **int()** so that you can add an integer to it.

simply use

```
print([int(i) - 11 for i in list])
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** `[int(x) - 11 for x in list1]`

First subtraction is not an operator defined on lists. It is defined for numpy arrays, for example, where only* numbers are used. Lists in python may contain anything so what should subtraction do? Some may say it should create a new list without the element `11` or at least its first occurrence. In any case, in reality your code will just fail by telling you lists do not know what it means to subtract.

Subtraction is also not defined on strings i.e. you can't expect `'33' - 11` to return `22`. Maybe in JavaScript you can but not in Python. Python will not try to convert any kind of object you give it to another type so that it can apply some operator or method. It prefers to just fail and tell you: if you wanted me to convert this object to an `int`, you should have told me.

Thus we are wrapping all objects in the list using `int()` which tries to convert any object it can into an `int`. This will fail for random objects like sockets but also for strings with illegal characters in them (like, you know, letters).

Once we have a list of `int` objects we can happily subtract another `int` from them, in this particular case `11`. Using Python's *list comprehension* we can combine both steps because what we want to do is essentially to map each element in the list to something else.